# SQL SELECT dulicate row add to column

Tags: mysql, sql, select

How to select duplicate content to column?

**TableA**

```
Id  title     prod_cat
--  --------- --------
1   product1  
2   product2 
3   product3
```

**TableB**

```
ID  category_title
--  --------------
1   category1
2   category2
3   category3
```

**TableC**

```
ID prod_id cat_id
-- ------- ------
1  1       1  
2  1       2  
3  2       3
```

How to show content like this? If product have multicategory in rows in table show category name in next column?

**TableOutput**

```
prod_id  cat_id    cat_id2
-------- --------- ----------
produkt1 category1 category2
produkt2 category3 NULL
produkt3 NULL      NULL
```

Comment: search around for "pivot". Tell us and add a tag of your sql language so we may help more.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis it's MYSQL

Comment: Are you looking for the result to have dynamic columns (e.g. if there are 6 duplicates they all end up on the same row), or are you only bothered about returning 2 cat_id columns?

Comment: @Monofuse if I have 6 duplicates they show only i one row

Comment: You could try building a query inside a script. So you've have 1 query which runs through a grabs distinct category_titles and the second while loop would build the columns and grab the values. I'm not aware of any dynamic way to grab an unknown amount of columns in MySql.

Comment: Build Queries: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999200/is-it-possible-to-execute-a-string-in-mysql Using While loop with MySQL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753337/while-syntax-error-in-mysql